# How to audit commands run by user inside a container in K8s

Tags: security, kubernetes

I want to audit commands that are being run by a user inside a running pod.

I know that kube-apiserver supports audit policies that allows you to log every request that is being done towards the API but as far as I know the API audit only records the exec command and not the inner commands run afterwards.

An approach that I thought is to have a sidecar container with auditbeat running but it's too heavy and the user might be able to kill it.

Comment: Maybe its an anti pattern for docker and kubernetes that user run commands inside containers/pods , this should not be allowed at first place

Comment: I think your sidecar approach is well. You can add a mutating webhook in your cluster, drop container `KILL` Cap, and inject the sidecar dynamically,

Answer (score 2):

The container should run a single process inside. It is not recommended to run a command inside container exception for testing. Most of our image doesn't have any type of shell.

If you have to spawn a shell and run a command inside, Then you need to think about is it possible to run that outside container?  If the main process is terminated but your shell commands are running in a container then k8s might not terminate that pod and recreate a new pod which might impact HA

Answer (score 0):

There are some commercial products that allow to do this. Few weeks ago I did a PoC for one of them.
The way it's implemented is that their product running as a pod (with 1 container inside) on the host level (host namespace / HostPID) and tracks usage of Docker daemon.