# Log command history to docker host

Tags: bash, docker, logging

I'm trying to make my system more robust to intrusions and one thing I'd like to do is log all the commands that are run inside a docker image. So this is different than just mounting the `.bash_history` file, say. It's about sending all shell commands to a log outside the image.

Is there a trick for this?

Once they're on the main system, I'll back them up remotely on a regular basis.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57452274/1032785

Comment: Typically everything you need to do to set up a container is in the Dockerfile, and it's committed to source control.  What are you trying to do that requires an interactive shell, with history, in a container?  How do you preserve similar history in non-container processes?

Comment: History is usually just kept in the `.bash_history` file for the host, though I'd like to do better there too. I'm not doing anything in the docker containers that requires this, but I want to keep an audit log of commands run in the containers, in case an intruder gains access.